# installing Java source code on OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-mavericks

I installed Java on my new laptop running OS X 10.9 Mavericks (downloaded from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US)...

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

However, when I start Eclipse, I can't view the Java source code. Where/How can I get the Java source code installed on my machine so that I can view it through Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and [install](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#install) the latest JDK 7 version from Oracle. On Mountain Lion, the source code is available in the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip` after the installation (if you have installed JDK 7u45).

Comment: Eclipse should find the source automatically when you tell it to use the JDK in the `Java / Installed JREs` preference.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do actually need to use Java 1.6 for some reason, Apple does provide the source code to the Apple versions of Java:

- Visit [Apple Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).
- Log in with your Apple developer ID.
- In the search box, type "java for os x"
- Download the latest Java for OS X Developer Package (at the time of this writing, it is "Java for OS X 2013-005 Developer Package").

As part of the installation, it provides a `src.jar` that you can attach in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Answer (score 1):

On Eclipse, go to `Navigate`, select `Open Type`, type in some JDK class, like `[java.lang.]String` and click `OK`. There should be a `Attach Sources` button that lets you select the source files. Navigate to your Java JDK installation and select the `src.zip` file that should be included.

Comment: What if your src.zip is not present ?


 me@host /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
 >> find . -iname "src.zip"

Returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

I think you only installed a Java Runtime Environment (JRE). To see the Java source code you need a Java Development kit (JDK). Oracle gives you the ability to downlad the JDK also for Mac OS X, so you should consider using this. Then you find a file src.zip inside the directory of the JDK and this will contain the source code.

Comment: No. Oracle does not have a JDK 6 for Mac OS X. The version he uses is the one by Apple, which does not include the `src.zip`. Besides, Oracle only provides JDK 6 up to 6u45 to the public (later versions are only provided to business partners). JDK 6u45 could be downloaded [`here`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html).